# how can i make interactive network graph?

Tags: networkx, interactive

I have plot a figure to highlight the gas flow and direction in gas network like [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vDZsl.png)

however, i wish make it interactive. I tried several ways but failed, is there idea to develop this?
many thanks!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 6):

You can use [pyvis](https://pyvis.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) package to get interactive graph in a static HTML file.

```py
import networkx as nx
from pyvis.network import Network


# Create directed graph with networkx
G = nx.DiGraph()
G.add_nodes_from([
    ('1', {'namespace': ['1n'], 'workload': {1: '1w'}}),
    ('2', {'namespace': ['2n'], 'workload': '2w'}),
    ('3', {'namespace': ['3n'], 'workload': '3w'}),
])
G.add_edges_from([
    ('1', '2', {'weight': 1}),
    ('2', '1', {'weight': 1}),
    ('2', '3', {'weight': 5}),
])

# Plot with pyvis
net = Network(
    directed = True,
    select_menu = True, # Show part 1 in the plot (optional)
    filter_menu = True, # Show part 2 in the plot (optional)
)
net.show_buttons() # Show part 3 in the plot (optional)
net.from_nx(G) # Create directly from nx graph
net.show('test.html')
```

The output HTML file will show this:[image]